# Queries with subcollections must use "storeAs" How should I solve this problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux-firebase

I am using react-redux-firestore v2.4
The error below happens
What is "storeAs"?
I would like to use subcollentions in this version.

https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore
but this version is not support "storeAs".

> Queries with subcollections must use "storeAs" to prevent invalid store updates. This closley matches the upcoming major release (v1), which stores subcollections at the top level by default.
> console. @ index.js:1

```
render()
{
return
<div>
subs = {project.subprojects?.content}
</div>
}
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect((props) => [
    { collection: "projects" },
    {
      collection: "projects",
      doc: props.match.params.id,
      subcollections: [{ collection: "subprojects" }]
    },
  ])
)(ProjectDetails);
```